# Sample application with .Net and Java EE

Tags: .net, jakarta-ee

I need a sample application where the UI part is made with .Net (Windows) and the database handling logic/Business Logic part is handled by Java EE.

Answer (score 1):

A better question is how would I do this?

One way would be to write the business logic in Java and expose it to the .NET client via a Web service, perhaps using [Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/) on the Java side.

On the .NET side [you could use WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) to create a service reference. There are various articles available on Google that [describe doing this](http://www.google.com/search?q=Apache+Axis+WCF).

I've done this myself in the past, only the other way round (exposing .NET Web services to Java clients).